# sending the elements of a select form to another one

Tags: javascript

it's my first post here and I so sorry if I wrong the place.
My difficulty is view the elements of the first select form to the other one if the first form is set as array.
The goal is to send the elements of a select form to another one and then record them on a db MySQL, that will show them on a html page.
I found in this forum the procedure how to create two select form and add 'n remove the items, then with the command .implode of MySQL can join the element and insert multiple items on db and view them on page.
But if I set the name's select form as array it doesn't work. I've used the following script to have two select form :

```
<script language="javascript">
function getOpt(select1,select2)
{
for (bCnt=0;bCnt<select1.length;bCnt++)
{
if (select1.options[bCnt].selected)
{
newOpt=new
Option(select1.options[bCnt].text,select1.options[bCnt].value,false,false);
select2.options[select2.length]=newOpt;
}
}
}

function remOpt(select2)
{
for (bCnt=0;bCnt<select2.length;bCnt++)
{
if (select2.options[bCnt].selected)
select2.options[bCnt]=null;
}
}
</script>
```

then the selects form:

```
<table border="0">
<tr>
<td>
<label for="id">List:<br></label>
<select name="oneS" id="select_role" size=20 required multiple="multiple"/>
<option value="101">101</option>
<option value="102">102</option>
<option value="103">103</option>
<option value="104">104</option>
<option value="105">105</option>
<option value="106">106</option>
</select>
</td>
<td>
<input type="button" value="Add"onClick="getOpt(this.form.oneS,this.for m.twoS)"><br>
<input type="button" value="Remove"onClick="remOpt(this.form.twoS)">
</td>
<td>
<label for="id">Members List:<br></label>
<select name="twoS" id="select_role" size=20 multiple="multiple"/>
</select>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

if comment the script,the part of the buttons, the second form and change the line:

```
<select name="oneS" id="select_role" size=20 required multiple="multiple"/>
```

in

```
<select name="oneS[]" id="select_role" size=20 required multiple="multiple"/>
```

I have any issue, can record the items of the first select form on db and view them on the page. 
But it's not my goal, I've have to use 2 select form. 
Is there some one can help me? thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I've you use jQuery, here it is:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
$('.add').click(function(event)//this is your first form, with the id "select_role"
{
$('#select_role2).html($(this).html()+"add whatever html code  you want to insert into here");
});
});
```

use the same idea for remove item.
then use an $.ajax or $.post to send the data to mysql or use a variable to store all the html that was added or removed from your second select.

Simply include the jQuery library and you are all sorted. I have not written raw JAvascript in a long long time, but this will work with the help of jQuery. don't use the same id for two elements again. The id must be unique.

Then assuming you insert a whole bunch of options, you can use `$('#your_form_id).serialize()` within an `$.ajax` call to get the array of elements then use the PHP technique for parsing  name="insertedoption[]" />. I'm not completely sure I helped you too much, as you need to read up on a few things, but this is an idea on how to do what you need to do.

Comment: An example of what exactly? Please be a tad more specific.

Comment: how to apply your script code on the my above code, I'm not expert of jQuery, just to understand it,the rest of the code I'll modify alone.

Comment: so, the javascript work's well now, the transfer from 1 form to other 1 is ok. The last step is to send the items selected and transferred on the second select form to a db MySQL as a single array. with my above example it doesn't work, any idea?? thanks a lot

Comment: I did give you all you need. Inserting options to the second form works, so now you need an ajax call with $(this).serialize() which will successfully send all the data you want to send without you needing to specifically select it. Or when you add or remove stuff use an array to keep track of it. Then serialize the array.

Comment: thanks a lot for your attention about my question, but I'm a beginning of java and I don't know any about ajax or Jquery.